# How can i use IndexOf to find an exact match?

Tags: c#, .net, indexof

I'm trying to use IndexOf to find the position of segment of a string. But the string could look like this:

```
blahblahEAPPWForms
EAPPWTextblah blah
EAPPWblah
```

The above examples could be in any order, but sometimes I may just be looking for "EAPPW" by itself, and it may not be there at all. But if the "EAPPWText" or "EAPPWForms" comes first, I get it's index.

Comment: So you want the index of "EAPPW" if it comes first but "EAPPWText" if it comes first? So the first instance of one of these?

Comment: As @inquisitive_mind said, what is wrong with `s.IndexOf("EAPPW");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is a bit confusing as it doesn't really explain if you want to only get the `"EAPPW"` string only all the time, or do you want to get it if it exists and if it doesn't you get any piece that starts with `"EAPPW"`

so, here is how to get both.
let's say you are looking for the word `"blah"` and only the word `"blah"`
you should be able to use regex to find it.
this regex searches for `"blah"`at the beginning, middle, end of the string and if it is the whole string.

the search method will return the index of first occurrence.

```
x = "this is blah";
reg = /^blah$|^blah\s+|\s+blah\s+|\s+blah$/;
var location = x.search(reg);
```

if you want to get "blahaaa" if "blah" doesn't exist, then you can check if the result is -1 then do indexOf.

```
if(location === -1)
{
   location = x.indexOf("blah");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple if you are looking for JUST that instance with no other text do:

```
  //Check if it's the whole string
  if(str == "EAPPWText")
     return 0;

  //Check if it's in the start or end
  int nIndex = str.IndexOf("EAPPWText" + " ");
  if(nIndex >= 0)
         return nIndex;

  //Check if it's the LAST word
  nIndex = str.IndexOf(" " + "EAPPWText" );
  return nIndex;
```